# How to check if a URL is accessible from HTTP client machine (obviously code is on server)

Tags: python, python-2.7, http, xmlhttprequest, cgi

I have my CGI script running on Machine S, Machine C access the cgi script, I want to check if a URL is accessible from HTTP client machine(Machine C) (obviously code is on server)

So Sitting on **Machine S** I am planning check connectivity between **Machine C** and the other Machine, **Machine O**.

Is this possible using only python CGI without using **JavaScript**?

Comment: common guys guide me in a direction atleast

Comment: i think that it would be impossible without javascript